# Replacing NULL values in a column with data in same column along with latitude & longitude

Tags: sql-server, null, data-cleaning, latitude-longitude

I am attempting to clean raw data which has station name (name), latitude (lat) and longitude (long) as float values.

Two questions

1. There are Null values in the (name) column which need to be replaced with name data from the table itself automatically. **How to do this?**
2. Some of the latitude and longitude combinations are not an exact match even after rounding off to 5 digits (see in example id no. 8). In such a case, ideally I would want to make the largest occurring combination of (lat) and (long) to prevail for that particular (name) with a range of +/- 0.00001. **How to do this?**

**Note**:

1. (lat) and (long) need to be rounded off to 5 decimal places which will give enough accuracy for this particular problem.
2. My actual data set has 1000 distinct unique station names and 100,000 rows to go through. So, doing it manually for each and every (name) will be time consuming.

Any help is appreciated.

Data input

| id | name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 41.0000016 | -47.000033 |
| 2 | aaa | 41.000002000001 | -47.000034005 |
| 3 | aaa | 41.0000018000001 | -47.000032 |
| 4 | **NULL** | 41.000001500002 | -47.0000315678 |
| 5 | bbb | 35.000023 | -27.0000045 |
| 6 | **NULL** | 35.000022 | -27.0000045 |
| 7 | bbb | 35.00002216 | -27.0000046 |
| 8 | **NULL** | 41.0000080000000 | -47.00004148900 |

Expected output

| id | name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 41.00000 | -47.00003 |
| 2 | aaa | 41.00000 | -47.00003 |
| 3 | aaa | 41.00000 | -47.00003 |
| 4 | aaa | 41.00000 | -47.00003 |
| 5 | bbb | 35.00002 | -27.00000 |
| 6 | bbb | 35.00002 | -27.00000 |
| 7 | bbb | 35.00002 | -27.00000 |
| 8 | aaa | 41.00001 | -47.00004 |

See below easy to replicate data.

```sql
Create TABLE sample (id int,names varchar(50), lat float, long float)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (1,'aaa', 41.0000016000000,-47.00003300000)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (2,'aaa', 41.0000020000010,-47.00003400500)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (3,'aaa', 41.0000018000001,-47.00003200000)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (4,NULL , 41.0000015000020,-47.00003156780)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (5,'bbb', 35.0000230000000,-27.00000450000) 
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (6,NULL , 35.0000220000000,-27.00000450000)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (7,'bbb', 35.0000221600000,-27.00000460000)
INSERT INTO sample VALUES (8,NULL , 41.0000080000000,-47.00004148900)
```

Comment: How do you know what `names` should be used for a row where the values of `names` is `NULL`?

Comment: The latitude and longitude should be reference for the station name. If the latitude and longitude is within +/- 0.00001, then it should mean the same location and same station name.

Comment: What is there are no other `names` with the same `lat` and `long`?

Comment: Kindly look at rounded off to 5 digits- lat and long shown in the "expected output" table.

Comment: I don't see any examples of where there isn't a matching `lat` and `long`; so what am I looking for here?

Comment: `FLOAT` is good for vehicles.  But, since it is binary, it won't necessarily show _or test_ as the equivalent 5-digit _decimal_ number.  So, you might consider `DECIMAL(7,5)` for latitude and `DECIMAL(8,5)` for longitude.

Comment: @Larnu, See table id no. 8. In this, the latitude and longitude are higher by 0.00001 that normal. Hence, it needs to correctly convert NULL to respective station name. My issue is that the dataset has 1000 distinct station names and around 10,000 NULLS. How can I write one command to auto fill all the NULLS with matching station name.

Comment: You've missed my point... What is there **isn't** a matching station? *"In this, the latitude and longitude are higher by 0.00001 that normal. Hence, it needs to correctly convert NULL to respective station name."* That doesn't answer my question of what if there *isn't* one.

Comment: @AjayP - Define "matching".  Equality of both lat and lng?  "Closest"?  Agreeing to 5 decimal places?  My point is that `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL` may 'look' the same, but 'be" different - hence an equality test may not work.

Comment: @Larnu, If there are no latitude and longitude matching criteria of +/- 0.00001, then it should return NULL since there is no match. I have a feeling that my question is not properly defined.

Comment: @Larnu- thank you for your questions. Made me realise that there are loopholes which need to be closed. I made a workaround. Created a separate master table with only distinct station names and fixed the lat and long co-ordinates to map out missing NULLs. Some locations had no matching name and I deleted it from the table. I close this question.

Comment: @RickJames, Thank you for your revert. I have not been able to use DECIMAL since it was not recognized in SQL SERVER. And I understand that there are some serious loop holes in my definition of match. I made a workaround with a new master table containing name, lat and long. Adding a new column to the main data base  helped to map missing NULLs. NULLs which do not have match were cleaned.